Firebase 10 deleteDoc does not throw an error when given incorrect Id
I have a function to delete employees like so
removeEmployee(empRefId: string): Observable<void>{
    const docRef = doc(this.firestore, 'empDetails/'+empRefId+'123'); //123 to corrupt Id
    const promise = deleteDoc(docRef);
    return from(promise);
  }

I call this from my component like so :
this.firebaseEmpService.removeEmployee(empRefId).subscribe({
        next: (result) => {          
          console.log("succesfully deleted emp in db");          
          this.toastrService.success("Deleted emp successfully ");
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error("Something went wrong:", error);          
          this.toastrService.error("Something went wrong");
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.log("On complete delete");          
          // Handle completion cases
        }
      });

When supplying an incorrect ID, I would have thought I will get an error. However, the error property of subscribe is never called.
I have surrounded the deletion call with try/catch and catch doesn't catch the promise's rejection - if it rejects at all.
    try{
      const promise = deleteDoc(docRef);
      console.log("Returning from try");      
      return from(promise);
    } catch(error)
    {
      console.log("Error in try catch");
      console.log(error);
    }
    return of();

The documentation doesn't say what happens when an incorrect Id is supplied - am only guessing the promise rejects. So, what am I doing wrong? Does deleteDoc not return an error? With what I have currently, the promise and observable both complete successfully, how do I tell the UI that an incorrect ID was passed?
I have tried to use the promise as is, but the catch block never executes:
this.firebaseEmpService.removeEmployeePromise(empRefId)
       .then((o) => {
         this.toastrService.success("Deleted emp successfully ");       
         })
         .catch((o) => {
           console.log("REJECTED", o);                    
           this.toastrService.error("Something went wrong");
         });


The call will indeed do nothing if the document doesn't exist.  This is the way it's worked for all client platforms for all versions.  If you need to know if you actually deleted the document, you should use a transaction and read the document first to check if it exists before deleting it.
